# Slick Grid - formatters.delete not showing in the grid when adding values by input type text

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

I have a grid with two columns: name and delete. When the user enters to an input text a value and clicks the button, that value is added to the grid. The problem is that the column "Delete" doesn't work,the column "Delete" doesn't display anything. See the code below:

```
grid = new Slick.Grid("#mygrid", gridData.Selections, columns, options);
grid.setSelectionModel(new Slick.CellSelectionModel());
$("#btnAddValue").click(function () {
    var newItem = { "SelectionName": $("#Name").val() };
    $('#pickListName').val('');
    var item = newItem;
    data = grid.getData();
    grid.invalidateRow(data.length);
    data.push(item);
    grid.updateRowCount();
    grid.render();
});

var columns = [
  { id: "SelectionName", name: "Name", field: "SelectionName", width: 420, cssClass: "cell-title", validator: requiredFieldValidator },
  { id: "Id", name: "Delete", field: "Id", width: 80, resizable: false, formatter: Slick.Formatters.Delete }];
var options = {
enableAddRow: true,
enableCellNavigation: true,
asyncEditorLoading: false,
autoEdit: true};
```

How should solve this?
Thank you

Comment: Please also include relevant code/information regarding  `Slick.Formatters.Delete`

Comment: Where do you set the `id` of `newItem`?